# Polymorphic subtyping in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, subtyping

I'm quite new to C++, and I need a clarify porting a project from Java.

In Java I can declare a base class and its derived, with generics, in this way:

```
public class GenericHost{
    public enum HostType{
        server,
        client
    }
    public HostType type_;
}

public class MyClient extends GenericHost{
    public String clientName;
}

public class MyServer extends GenericHost{
    public String serverName;
}



public abstract class GenericNetwork<hostType extends GenericHost> {
    public enum NetworkType{
        central,
        peripheral
    }
    private NetworkType type_;
    protected hostType masterHost;
    public hostType getMasterHost(){
        return masterHost;
    }
    public abstract String getName();
}

public class CentralNetwork extends GenericNetwork<MyServer>{
    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return masterHost.serverName;
    }
}

public class PeripheralNetwork extends GenericNetwork<MyClient>{
    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return masterHost.clientName;
    }
}
```

---

This allows me to:

1. In derived classes I'm allowed to use methods and variables of specified derived class (e.g. `serverName` / `clientName` in `CentralNetwork` / `PeripheralNetwork`) and not only of the base class
2. Derived class is tiped, so the compiler / editor can suggest me every method & variable during code editing
3. I'm forced to use a class that is derived from the base class (`GenericNetwork` / `GenericHost`), every error is at compile time and not run time
4. Every method / variable that use generics will be treated in derived class as the child class and not the base class (e.g. in `CentralNetwork`, the `getMasterHost` will return the derived `MyServer`, not the base `GenericHost`).

I wish to know if does exist anything similar in C++.
I already looked for templates, inheritance and subtyping but I can't find a way to do something smarter like I did in Java. I hope I missed something...

EDIT:
This what I tried in C++:

```
class GenericHost{
    public enum HostType{
        server,
        client
    }
    public HostType type_;
}

class MyClient : public GenericHost{
    public String clientName;
}

class MyServer : public GenericHost{
    public String serverName;
}

template<class hostType : GenericHost>             <--WISH, forced base class
class GenericNetwork {
    public enum NetworkType{
        central,
        peripheral
    }
    private NetworkType type_;
    protected hostType masterHost;
    public hostType getMasterHost(){
        return masterHost;             <--WISH, should return MyServer / Myclient in derived class
    }
    public virtual std::string getName();
}

class CentralNetwork<MyServer> : public GenericNetwork{
    public std::string getName(){
        return masterHost.serverName;             <--WISH, tiped and suggested by editor / compiler
    }
}

class PeripheralNetwork<MyClient>: public GenericNetwork{
    public std::string getName(){
        return masterHost.clientName;             <--WISH, tiped and suggested by editor / compiler
    }
}
```

I don't have the C project with me now, so I rewrote it on the fly, sorry for any mistake...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried in C++ (with templates)?

Comment: Please prepend all lines in a code block with four spaces, or select it and press Ctrl+K in order to get proper formatting. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @dyp done, sorry, my first post...

Comment: Can you use C++11 features (i.e. does your compiler support them)?

Comment: I'm currently using gcc-4.8, can you point me to a link about C++11 features do you mean? I can try.

Comment: g++4.8.1 is a feature complete C++11 compiler. I.e. it supports all (core) language C++11 features. g++4.8 seems almost feature complete, according to http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html You'll just have to use the `-std=c++11` option.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no explicit feature that lets you do this. You can use `static_cast` though, which will give you a compile time error if the types are not compatible.

```
template <class hostType>
class GenericNetwork {
public:
    GenericNetwork() {
        static_cast<GenericHost*>((hostType*)nullptr); // or 0 or NULL if not C++11
    }
};
```

If `hostType` and `GenericHost` are compatible, the cast will succeed but do nothing. Otherwise, you'll get a compile time error.

Comment: thanks parkovski this solves the 3rd point, but I also need the others.

Comment: @SilverHawk As far as I can see, this (and my) approach solve all but 2 (and maybe even that, I'm not quite sure what the context is). With templates, you don't lose static type safety in C++.

Answer (score 0):

There's no dedicated feature to explicitly constrain template arguments (*), but you can use (C++11's)

```
static_assert( std::is_base_of<GenericHost, hostType>::value,
               "The template argument must be derived from GenericHost" );
```

<sub>(*) There'll be template constraints hopefully in C++17.</sub>

This is a compile-time assertion and can be used as a declaration:

```
template<class hostType>
class GenericNetwork {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of<GenericHost, hostType>::value,
                   "The template argument must be derived from GenericHost" );

public:
    enum NetworkType{
        central,
        peripheral
    }

    virtual ~GenericNetwork(); // you typically want a virtual dtor in an ABC

    hostType& getMasterHost(){ // you might want to return a (const) reference
        return masterHost;
    }

    virtual std::string getName() = 0; // abstract

private:
    NetworkType type_;
    hostType masterHost;  // or protected

    // consider making the copy ctor and copy assignment op protected
    // to prevent unintended slicing
}
```

Comment: I have to give a try, for all the points, I'll let you know. For now, _Thanks_.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody points out, C++ templates can implement this so it doesn't merit dedicated syntax.

Here's a rather literal translation that enforces the baseclass requirement by simply doing it.

```
#include <string>
struct GenericHost {
        enum HostType { server,client } type_;
};

template<class GenericHost=GenericHost>
struct MyClient : GenericHost     {  std::string clientName;  };    

template<class GenericHost=GenericHost>
struct MyServer : GenericHost     {  std::string serverName;  };


template< template<class> class SpecificHost, class GenericHost=GenericHost >
struct GenericNetwork
{
        typedef SpecificHost<GenericHost> hostType;
        virtual ~GenericNetwork() { };

        enum NetworkType { central, peripheral };

        hostType             getMasterHost() { return masterHost; }
        virtual std::string  getName() = 0;


protected: hostType     masterHost;
private:   NetworkType  type_;
};


struct CentralNetwork : GenericNetwork<MyServer> {
        std::string getName() { return masterHost.serverName; }
};

struct PeripheralNetwork : GenericNetwork<MyClient> {
        std::string getName() { return masterHost.clientName; }
};


// testing: force instantiation:
struct CentralNetwork makeme;
struct PeripheralNetwork metoo;
std::string doit() { return makeme.getName() + metoo.getName(); }
```

I believe this gets all four desiderata, though the errors would be detected in different places.  As others point out `static_cast<requiredBase*>((testedClass*)0);` can do that job, but  bypassing the protection takes work, not just a mistake, and it would show up in the type system so I don't see the point.

(edit: add the virtual destructor, no dessert for me tonight. Bad dog.)

Comment: Is there any reason because you used structs instead of classes?

Comment: @SilverHawk When the `public` default for structs does a better job describing overall accessibility of the innards, I use it.

Comment: @SilverHawk one thing just occurred to me: if I understand correctly, class variables in Java are always reference types, even those that are already class members like your `masterHost`, and if so you're expecting your `getMasterHost()` to return a reference to the actual masterhost object -- which it will, in Java, and won't, in C++.  Instead it will return a separate copy of the embedded object allocated on the stack if anywhere and destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: I tried your example, and it works. But I haven't understood how and why. Can you give me a link or a piece of paper regarding this trick? I WANT to know what I'll code. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @SilverHawk I'm sorry, I can't see anything I'd regard as a trick. Will you say what part's purpose or effect isn't clear?  It's all for effect, no boilerplate, some of it's there to make other code easy to do correctly -- templating the `MyClient` and `MyServer` base, for instance, exposes the type relationship to templates, and the `GenericNetwork` template uses that relationship, whereas the parameter defaults just make implementing and using it correctly effortless to write and read (and doing it wrong take visible effort).  I'm good for a few more rounds if that doesn't help :-)